# What does <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/> mean in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I am new to XML world and just read an example XSLT file found this line of code that I don't quite understand:
`<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>`

My understanding is `<xsl:apply-templates select\>` will find the corresponding `<xsl:template match\>` and apply that template.
But @* according to my understanding, means match any attribute.
So does this line of code `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>` means that, it will look for all the `<xsl:template match\>` no matter what it match as long as it match an attribute, and then apply all the templates it matched?

I am so confused, not sure if I got it right.

Comment: @michael.hor257k That should be an answer not a comment.

Comment: @MichaelKay I bow to your superior judgement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
```

tells the processor to:

1. Select all attributes of the current element;
2. For each attribute in the selected set, find the template that matches it **best** and apply it (and only it).

From the XSLT 1.0 specification:

[5.1 Processing Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#section-Processing-Model)

> A node is processed by finding all the template rules with patterns that match the node, and choosing the best amongst them; the chosen rule's template is then instantiated ...

[5.5 Conflict Resolution for Template Rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#conflict)

> It is possible for a source node to match more than one template rule. The template rule to be used is determined as follows:
> ...
> Next, all matching template rules that have lower priority than the matching template rule or rules with the highest priority are eliminated from consideration.
> ...
> It is an error if this leaves more than one matching template rule. An XSLT processor may signal the error; if it does not signal the error, it must recover by choosing, from amongst the matching template rules that are left, the one that occurs last in the stylesheet.

I am using XSLT 1.0 terminology because you did not say which version you use. In XSLT 2.0 and higher you can use the `xsl:next-match` instruction to apply effectively more than one template to the same node. In XSLT 1.0 this is only possible using the `xsl:apply-imports` instruction.

Recommended reading:
https://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/